# flutter web app without html, css and javascript

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know that if it is possible to make flutter app for web without using HTML, css or javascript and only using flutter and dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely possible to create a web app using flutter and dart.

To add web support in the existing flutter project you can run the command `flutter create .` and to release it run the command `flutter build web`

For testing your app in chrome you can use command `flutter run -d chrome`

You can disable android support using command `flutter config --no-enable-android` and disable ios support using command `flutter config --no-enable-ios`

Comment: I want to know that if Ii is possible to write an app specifically for web platform no Android or iOS, the app will work as a web app like we create web app in angular or react (target platform of the app will be web only)

Comment: have a look at the updated answer! @Shailendra

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is not need to build web app with HTML,CSS & JS, your flutter code alone will work.

Note: try `flutter upgrade` bcs v-2.0.0 stable release for web got released

Comment: I want to know that if Ii is possible to write an app specifically for web platform no Android or iOS, the app will work as a web app like we create web app in angular or react (target platform of the app will be web only)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Dart/Flutter exclusively to build web apps. You don't need to write any HTML/CSS/Javascript.

You can setup your project from the terminal (like previous comments suggests), or you can use an IDE such Android Studio, or you can use Visual Studio.

If you use Android Studio, you can create a new Flutter Project, and select the 'web' platform only, and de-select Android and IOS.

I am currently using Dart/Flutter to build web apps only. Android Studio builds the HTML/CSS/Javascript for you. Then you just have to publish it into a web server (online or local).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Flutter for web apps but though it is in early stage of development about how the web app will be stable or not